# Weird class name conflict in Swift3 with Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I'm working with Core Data. Here is the class(generated by editor).

```
public class Tag: NSManagedObject {

}
```

And I defined an enum whose case has the same name as above.

```
enum NoteListType {
    case Tag
    case Album
}
```

When I tried to build it, I got this error message.

> Use of undeclared type 'Tag'

When I CMD-click `Tag` to jump to its definition, it shows two options. Please help me. Many thanks in advance.

**Update:**
I tried to rename enum cases but still got `undeclared type`. Maybe it's caused by Xcode 8.2.1 and Core Data.
And I have published my project on Github. Here is the [link](https://github.com/lumialxk/HappyShare).

Comment: Conforming to the naming convention – class and enum names start with a capital letter, enum cases start with a lowercase letter - could solve the issue.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.

Comment: @vadian I know this is recommended in Swift 3. But my project converted to Swift 3 just now. I will try this, thanks!

Comment: i don't get any error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I downloaded your git project and found out that this conflict is arising because of Target Membership of each file has both entity and Target so OS was unable to detect which class is referenced. I checked out the membership from Entity (kept only target) and the Tag ,Album were detected. Although I was unable to run the code as  i got some compile team errors as  you were trying to directly type cast NSManagedObject at some places . Please refer below screenshot . [image]

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: With your answer, I solved this problem finally. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this ..

```
enum NoteListType {
    case tag
    case album
}
```

Comment: This is good since by convention enumeration cases should be lower case.